# How do I know which GLM family to use?

Tags: regression, self-study, distributions, mathematical-statistics, generalized-linear-model

I have the following question:
[image]

I need to specify the distribution, link function and linear predictor. I know how to do find the link function and linear predictor if I know the first but don't know how to choose the correct distribution. If anyone knows how or has any advice that would be great.

Comment: The nature of the dependent variable (the number of customers) gives an indication of what could be a first guess. What is a common distribution for modelling counts? Also: If this is a homework question, please add the `self-study` tag.

Comment: Would this be a Poisson distribution? And thanks! Sorry this is my first time

Comment: Yes, a Poisson distribution would be my first guess, given the information.

Comment: Getting a good link is usually more crucial. Here use of a log link follows from the crucial fact that the mean outcome can only be positive.

Comment: Ok great thank you!